# How to get jquery hint and mysql retrieval working together

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a textfield which retrieves data from mysql. However I also have a jQuery hint which is 'insert here' but now it does not retrieve the value from mysql.

How do I get both working?

```
<input type="text" title="insert here" value=<?php echo $row['name']?> />
```

Comment: Add more code, please! The javascript and the php part which is working with the jquery hint (I'm also not familiar with the plugin, so a link to it would help as well).
Help us so we can help you!

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple concept. In your submit handler you are clearing **ALL** the values of the "hint" elements and then browser submits form. Values are gone when it submits. Following will only clear any values that match the hint value

```
//Clear input hints on form submit
$('form').submit(function() {
    $('input.hint').val(function( i, old){
        return  (old== this.title) ? '' : old;  
    });
    return true;
});
```

EDIT: you should consider some validation prior to submit also

Comment: it is the same submit handler as you already have with a slight modification.. swap old for new

Comment: i copied and pasted instead of my original and it still showing inserty here but not the email address

Comment: there is no code anywhere above to retrieve from server other than `<?php echo $row3['name']?>`. There is no way to know where that comes from in code you have posted. Here...I cleansed up the "hints" jQuery to replace all that you have   http://jsfiddle.net/jzCeq/

Comment: thanks, i am also looking to change the jquery hint text colour. Currently it is the same colour as the textfield however I would like it to be different!

Comment: simple css will take care of the color